# Req.body is empty for POST request in Express

Tags: javascript, express

I try to use Postman for generating some post transaction of my web but when I check the post method of my code it print the empty {} and add the empty {} to my list. I try to use middleware but the problem is still occurring.

This is my code.

```js
// my code at restaurant.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const restaurants = require("../data")

router.get("/",(req,res) =>{
    res.json(restaurants);
}
)

router.get("/:id",(req,res) =>{
    const restaurantid = Number.parseInt(req.params.id,10);
    const restaurant = restaurants.find((restaurant) => restaurant.id === restaurantid);
    res.json(restaurant);
})

router.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    new_restaurant = req.body;
    restaurants.push(new_restaurant);
    res.json(new_restaurant);
}
)

module.exports = router;

//my code at index.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

const restaurantsRouter = require("./routes/restaurants.js");

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
// Routes
app.use("/apis/restaurants",restaurantsRouter);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("<h1>Hello Express</h1>");
});
app.listen(3000,()=> {
    console.log("Listening to port 3000");
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Which version of Postman do you use?

Comment: You need to show how you post the data with Postman.

Comment: I use version 7.32.0 I post a JSON form of data

Comment: @PolapobRatanachayoto, I updated my answer. Try it and let me know if it works

Comment: Why  does `index.js` export an empty router that is never used in the code you show?

Answer (score 0):

The general reasons for an empty `req.body` on an incoming POST request are as follows:

1. You are failing to send the body properly with whatever client is sending the request.
2. You are failing to set the right content-type with the request that matches the type of the body data you are sending.  If you're sending JSON, then you will need to make sure the incoming request has the content-type `application/json`.
3. You don't have the right middleware installed or working properly that will match the incoming content-type, read the body from the incoming stream, parse it and put the parsed results in `req.body`.
4. The middleware for parsing that content-type is not registered before your route handler in Express.
5. Some other middleware is "eating" the body before your middleware so the body is empty when it gets to your JSON middleware.

So, you will need to go through your POST request and eliminate each of these possibilities until you find the problem.